# How to specify a filter to exclude hdfs file of a partition when calling distcp -update?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, distcp

Hadoop `distcp -update` is used with a filter. I want to exclude the hdfs file of the partition `dt=20230621`. What should I do? The command I am using now is

`$ hadoop distcp -update -append -filters ".*dt=20230621.*" /tmp/source /tmp/target`

...but the partition `dt=20230621` below is still being backed up while I'd like to avoid copying these files.

Comment: If i'm not mistaken `-filters` option requires you to specify a **file** that contains the list of patterns to be excluded.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I put .*dt=20230621.* into the txt file and filter but it still doesn’t work. The error message is error tools.regexcopufilter:can’t findfilters file -^(.*/)dt=20230621 (/.*$ )

Comment: Sorry, my file name is wrong, stupid to myself